# Format this GET request in VB.NET code behind?

Tags: vb.net, webrequest

I am trying a "GET" method to request a count of activities from the Accelo API here:

https://api.accelo.com/docs/?http#count-activities

And although i've used a very similar POST method to successfully get the access token using an authentication method, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the count of activities.  The API says to use "GET" and past the access token as "bearer..." and I've also tried doing a post and getting the stream first, tried sending in some data and accessing the "list activities" endpoint instead...nothing is working. everything I do returns the error "400. Bad Request."

I've tried passing data in a query string format directly in the URI, and tried passing no data since its a GET function. It looks to me like I'm following the API exactly.

```
 Dim data2 = Nothing ' Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonstring)
    Dim _list = GetListOfActivities(New Uri("https://example.api.accelo.com/api/v0/activities/count.xml"), data2, _AccessToken)

Dim reqa As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri)
    ' reqa.Method = "GET"
    reqa.Headers.Add("GET", "/api/v0/activities/count.xml HTTP/1.1")
    reqa.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " & _AccessToken)
    reqa.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    'reqa.ContentLength = jsonDataBytes.Length

    ' Dim streama = reqa.GetRequestStream()
    ' streama.Write(jsonDataBytes, 0, jsonDataBytes.Length)
    'streama.Close()

    Dim responsea As WebResponse = reqa.GetResponse()
    Console.WriteLine((CType(responsea, HttpWebResponse)).StatusDescription)
```

I must be formatting the request wrong - please help?

Comment: GSerg, thank you but that did not help. I've also tried that in the commented code portion. Getting the same exception.

Comment: In WebRequest.Create(uri) what exactly is URI and What is the purpose of reqa.Headers.Add("GET", "/api/v0/activities/count.xml HTTP/1.1")

Comment: This looks like option strict is not turned on (there's no way for the compiler to infer the type of `data2`). This is **very bad**. Pleas turn on Option Strict or Option Infer, and then fix all the compiler errors the come up because of the change. Your code will be so much better and less error-prone for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem turned out to be something stupid, and literally beyond the scope of what I posted here. I had specified a "scope" in my initial request to get the access token that was set to read-only "staff" data (I had copied-and-pasted their example online into my code, for other parameters like grant type, and I brought the scope along with it), and in this scenario here I was trying to access "activities" data and not "staff" data. I would have thought I'd get a permissions-related error, instead of "bad request" which confused me, but anyway it works now.

The above code - actually with this line:

```
reqa.Method = "GET"
```

instead of this line:

```
reqa.Headers.Add("GET", "/api/v0/activities/count.xml HTTP/1.1")
```

Works just fine since I changed my scope to read(all) in my initial web method getting the access token.